# How to find the top or max Column value of a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Having the following table which is some kind of an http request logs:

```
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+
| County  |  Mobile  |    OS     | Browser  |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+
| USA     | iPhone   | iOS       | Safar    |
| UK      | Samsung  | Android   | Chrome   |
| India   | Motorola | Android   | Chrome   |
| India   | Nokia    | Android   | Chrome   |
| Russia  | Nokia    | Microsoft | Edge     |
| Germany | Sony     | Android   | Chrome   |
| India   | Sony     | Android   | Chrome   |
| Russia  | Nokia    | Microsoft | Edge     |
| Germany | Sony     | Android   | Chrome   |
| India   | Motorola | Android   | Chrome   |
| Russia  | Nokia    | Android   | Edge     |
| Germany | Sony     | Android   | Chrome   |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

How to find the most used mobile phone, OS, and browser per county and get a result like

```
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+
| County  |  Mobile  |    OS     | Browser  |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+
| USA     | iPhone   | iOS       | Safar    |
| UK      | Samsung  | Android   | Chrome   |
| India   | Motorola | Android   | Chrome   |
| Russia  | Nokia    | Microsoft | Edge     |
| Germany | Sony     | Android   | Chrome   |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

So the most used mobile phone in USA is iPhone and the most used OS is iOs and the most used browser is Safar and so forth ...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (The answer won't be the same...)

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use.

Comment: Hi, based on the information you have provided, it is not possible to determine the criteria for your expected output - there is no way of knowing what brands are more popular than others. Please amend your question to explain this. Also, are you using mysql or oracle?

Comment: @Jens I really have no clew what to try ...

Comment: @BarryPiccinni I would say the highest count per city is what the OP is looking for

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql)

Comment: @jarlh Doesn't matter I just want a clew how to go about this ... to be honest I am using Hive but I first want to know how to do it in MySQL or Oracle from there I can continue ...

Comment: if MySQL 8+, window functions will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DBMS support window function, you can try this.

Try to use `CTE` write subquery get the `COUNT` by `County` , `Mobile`,`OS`,`Browser` colnums and use `row_number` make row number by `cnt` then get `rn=1`.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   County VARCHAR(50),
     Mobile VARCHAR(50),
     OS VARCHAR(50),
     Browser VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('USA','iPhone', 'iOS', 'Safar');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('UK','Samsung', 'Android' , 'Chrome');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('India','Motorola','Android' , 'Chrome');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('India','Nokia','Android', 'Chrome');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Russia','Nokia','Microsoft', 'Edge');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Germany','Sony','Android','Chrome');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('India','Sony','Android','Chrome');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Russia','Nokia','Microsoft','Edge');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Germany','Sony','Android','Chrome');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('India','Motorola','Android','Chrome');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Russia','Nokia','Android','Edge');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Germany','Sony','Android','Chrome');
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte as (
  select County,Mobile,OS,Browser,COUNT(*) cnt
  from T
  GROUP BY County,Mobile,OS,Browser
)
SELECT 
    t1.County,
    t1.Mobile,
    t1.OS,
    t1.Browser 
FROM (
  select t1.*,row_number() over(partition by County order by cnt desc) rn
  from cte t1
) t1
where t1.rn = 1
ORDER BY COUNTY desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d39d4/11/0)**:

```
|  COUNTY |   MOBILE |        OS | BROWSER |
|---------|----------|-----------|---------|
|     USA |   iPhone |       iOS |   Safar |
|      UK |  Samsung |   Android |  Chrome |
|  Russia |    Nokia | Microsoft |    Edge |
|   India | Motorola |   Android |  Chrome |
| Germany |     Sony |   Android |  Chrome |
```

Comment: I am trying it and it seems to work ... but can you please explain the part of the query "select t1.*,row_number() over(partition by County order by cnt desc) rn
  from cte t1" specially "from cte t1" do you join cte and t1 or  ?

Comment: In general can you please add some explanation ?

Comment: Because you seem to want to get the heigher amount by country.
So you can try to use row_number make row number `order by` amount desc , then get top 1 by each country

Comment: More information you can see doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it will work in oracle

```
select * from 
(select max(rn) rn1 ,country
from
(
select *, row_number over partition by (Mobile, OS,Browser order by County) as rn
from tablename)a)x inner join 
(
select *, row_number over partition by (Mobile, OS,Browser order by County) as rn
from tablename)b on b.rn=x.rn1 and b.country=x.country
```